# Linking an img with css file path issue

Tags: html, css, file, background-image, filepath

```
body {
  background: url("images/bg/cloud.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
</head>
```

root folder has css folder with index.css in it.  root folder also has images and bg folder with cloud.jpg in it.

When the css is in the root directory it works fine. However once I move it the css file within a css folder and relink it via the new html path it can find the image! I feel like the css file is searching for the images file and cant find it. It needs to go BACK/OUT of the css folder THEN search for the images/bg/cloud.jpg? I think i am on the right track, does it make a difference if i did /images vs images? and also does adding .. make me go back a layer in the folder hierarchy?

it seems like I can have the image file inside a folder but not the css file or my file path is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **images folder** and **css folder** are in the root.

Change this:

`background: url("images/bg/cloud.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;`

To this:

`background: url("../images/bg/cloud.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;`

It is because of the relative path from the `.css` file, adding the `../` makes the file path go back one file (back to the root in this case).

Comment: okay that makes sense, it still seems not to work. in this project i have other images linked to these same folders working fine. it may be having issues because its a background img? here is a link to the repo, any help much appreciated! https://github.com/bencasalino/bencasalino.github.io

Comment: As you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/vkavj6t8/ you are using the background correctly. I will look at your code, give me a minute.

Comment: @BenjaminCasalino you have two `index.css` files (one in the root and one in the css folder) you updated the `index.css` that is in your root. You need to update the `index.css` that is in your **css folder** instead.

Comment: yes that did, i was still linking from my old css file and not the new one in the css folder!!

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the relative paths. You have to add dots and a slash. Like think of the css file wants to find the image from where itself is. Use:

```
background: url("../images/bg/cloud.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
```

This should work.

With the two dots you say move one folder out, like out of /css/ and then into /images/...